# Images on UISegmentedControl doesn't show properly

Tags: ios, ios7

I have added images to each segment via XCode:

[image]

However the images showup as blue on white.

[image]

This is how each segment should look like:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is it affected by tintColor?

Comment: yes indeed. It is affected.

Comment: @Houman do you find a solution for this?

Comment: I don't think there was a solution to this. I had to accept it and move on if memory serves right.

Answer (score 0):

The control is using the alpha values in the source image to create the displayed images (and then applying the tint colour). You have no control over this. If you want to use your own images with full colour you will need to create a custom control (or find a 3rd party implementation).